# How can I get a refund from TAP after they rescheduled my flight?

Tags: refunds, tap-portugal

I have purchased non refundable tickets from TAP and they moved the flights more than 5 hours. Under EU law, if your flights are moved more than 5 hours you are entitled to a refund. How do I claim it?

Comment: How far in advance were you notified? Where were you flying? How was this presented to you? Were you offered a choice to accept this new schedule or not? I would tend to analyze this as a cancellation and the rules depend on how timely the notification was and the length of the flight.

Comment: Note: it doesn't depends on the departure delay, but the actual arrival time delay. The distance of departure and arrival airports is also important.

Comment: Claiming a refund is one thing. Actually getting it is quite another. There are a number of questions on this site from people who have had trouble getting their refund from TAP.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.